# What does 利口耳丝耳 and 利口丝久 mean?

Tags: simplified-characters, technology

Here's a screenshot from the [1point3acres](https://www.1point3acres.com/bbs/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=547521&extra=page%3D5&mobile=2) forums:

> [image]

it says:

> 1. 利口耳丝耳
> 2. 利口丝久

What does this mean? Is it a transliteration from English?

You can also find phrases like:

> 利口 斯尔
>   利口 丝丝久

on the site.

Any ideas?

---

Edit: they seem to be "interview question types"

[Uber ATG](https://www.1point3acres.com/bbs/interview/uber-software-engineer-488521.html) failed interview:

> 一道利口斯尔，一道利口散灵思

[startup Element, Inc.](https://www.1point3acres.com/bbs/interview/data-science-473184.html) failed interview:

> 利口散灵思->这个不是算每个点到(0,0) square 的 sum 相减么。。还有啥最优解？莫非是Segment tree 或者 binary indexed tree?

Comment: From here: https://www.1point3acres.com/bbs/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=547521&extra=page%3D5&mobile=2?

Comment: Yes @user3306356. Could you please translate it for me. Thank you!

Comment: Please pay for translation service

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 Do you understand what they're saying? I'd be willing to put some bounty up for it, out of pure curiosity.

Comment: I am in the same situation, would anyone would be kind enough to tell me what these two phrases mean: 利口-夭舞物 and 利口-夭尔七

Comment: @RishabhJain 利口-夭舞物 = Leet Code 155 & 利口-夭尔七 = Leet Code 127

Answer (score 6):

I believe 利口 is the Chinese for:

[Leet Code](https://leetcode.com/)

> [a] platform to help you enhance your skills, expand your knowledge and prepare for technical interviews.

---

and the rest are just numbers:

- 耳丝耳 = 242
- 丝久 = 49
- 斯尔 = 12
- 散灵思 = 304
- 丝丝久 = 449

Although there might be some mistakes in the numbers there.

---

If we take 利口散灵思 for example that gives us: LeetCode 304 which is a [question](https://blog.csdn.net/fuxuemingzhu/article/details/83537572) about:

> Range Sum Query 2D - Immutable（Python）

---

Now back to the question at hand:

- [Leetcode 22. Generate Parentheses](https://blog.csdn.net/happyaaaaaaaaaaa/article/details/51525303)
- [LeetCode 19. Remove Nth Node From End of List](https://blog.csdn.net/camellhf/article/details/72614638)

---

p.s.: the offical name for Leet Code in Chinese seems to be:

> 力扣

maybe the alternative translation adds to the code.

---

[Leet Code](https://leetcode.com/articles/) has a list of articles here ordered by number.

Comment: 阁下神人也，这也能看出来！拜服，拜服。

Comment: WOW!!!! Didn't know such a sub-linquistic culture exist. What will they think of next?

Comment: cool, I think `耳丝耳` means `242` here